# Is $C^n [a,b]$ a Banach Space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Prove that the space **$C^n [a,b]$** of all n-times continuously differentiable functions x on $[a,b]$ with $$||x||_{n}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}||x^{(i)}||_{\infty}$$ is a **Banach Space**.
Here $x^{(i)}$ stands for the i-th derivative of x.

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Comment: This is a standard exercise/result. All you've done with it on this site is echo it to us. What is your context? What do you know about the $n=0$ case? The $n=1$?

Comment: $C[a,b]$ forms Banach Space under Sup norm, now if I can show this a closed subspace of $C[a,b]$, then I can show that this also a Banach Space. What I want is to show this space as a closed subspace of $C[a,b]$.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:

- $|x_n^{(i)}(t)-x_m^{(i)}(t)|\leq\|x_n^{(i)}-x_m^{(i)}\|\leq \|x_n-x_m\|$ so any Cauchy sequence is Cauchy in the derivatives pointwise, including the $0th$ derivative. Then you can use the completeness of the reals to arrive at limiting function $x(t)$.
- Use triangle inequalities and continuous derivatives to prove that derivatives of $x(t)$ exist and are continuous.
- After you prove the claim for $n=1$, it's a trivial extension to add more derivatives.